# Multi touch with web cam

Tags: webcam, multi-touch

I found the following article 
[Multi-touch in Ubuntu using a webcam and your hands](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/multi-touch-in-ubuntu-using-a-webcam-and-your-hands-video/). 
Can some one tell me how to use my laptop camera to control ubuntu 12.04. like it is done in the video?
To control presentations with hand movement & more functions.

Comment: There are entire projects on multitouch.  They're all still alpha-prealpha as far as I know.  Kind of an if you're asking, it's probably best not to spawn a thousand more questions type of thing.  it can be done: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4g3cdgoU78&feature=related but it's definitely NOT a string of apt-get installs

Comment: if you want to talk about it try the chat feature at the top.  I made a multitouch room and explicitly granted access to you.  not sure how to do an invite to chat from someone that's not in chat.  if you enter the room type a message to @aking1012 so I hear you

Comment: I cannot chat since I don't have enough reputation points

Comment: Is there some kind of program that maybe uses something like opencv that from the normal web cam from the laptop recognise the hand/ finger gesture to control the computer. like the xbox kinect.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, are you still looking for an answer? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!